# Code to determining percent difference between three values

Tags: excel, openpyxl, python-3.6

I want to find the percent difference between three values in a single column and transfer the percent difference to a new column

```
Lets say I have the following values to compare: 
**Value1** = 5 
**Value2** = 8 
**Value3** = 2
```

I need to subtract Value2 from Value1 and Value3 and I also need to subtract Value1 from Value3.

I would like a simple way to find the max value in a triplicate and subtract the remaining two values to find the percent difference then find the second highest values and subtract the lowest value to find its percent difference.

Perhaps I am approaching this all wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
****CODE*****

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('05.16.17 CaMKII Sean RD.xlsx', read_only= False, data_only = True)


sheet = wb['Sheet1']

### Protein Max Value for Triplicate 

for i in range(2,3):
    sheet['D{}'.format(i)] = '=max(C2:C4)'.format(i)
for i in range(2,3):
    sheet['E{}'.format(i)] = '=((D2-C2)/(D2+C2) * 100)'.format(i)
for i in range(3,4):
    sheet['E{}'.format(i)] = '=((D2-C3)/(D2+C3) * 100)'.format(i)
for i in range(4,5):
    sheet['E{}'.format(i)] = '=((C3-C2)/(C2+C3) * 100)'.format(i)


wb.save('camdatapolishedoutput.xlsx')
```

Comment: You can use `LARGE(n)` to return the n'th largest value in a range

Comment: Use `sheet.cell(row=x, col=y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your code clearly but it seems like you are looking for **`FormatPercent`** formula. And also you have to change many parts of your code. Here below I've corrected lots of them but as long as I can't know what you are really trying to do, the rest will be yours.

```
 Dim wb as Workbook, sheet as Worksheet
 Dim wsArrD2 As Range, wsArrC2 As Range, wsArrC3 As Range, wsArrC4 As Range
 Dim yourdesktopaddress as String
 yourdesktopaddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
 Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(yourdesktopaddress & "\05.16.17 CaMKII Sean RD.xlsx")
 ''This code finds your Desktop address and opens the specific file.

 Set sheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 'I assume you were looking for information from that file's Sheet1 sheet.

 Set wsArrD2 = sheet.Range("D2")
 Set wsArrC2 = sheet.Range("C2")
 Set wsArrC3 = sheet.Range("C3")
 Set wsArrC4 = sheet.Range("C4")

 Dim maxC as Long, PercentVar1 as String
 Dim PercentVar2 as String, PercentVar4 as String
'You should define your '%' variables as String otherwise you will get an Run Time 13 Error'

 maxC = Evaluate("=MAX(C2:C4)")
 PercentVar1 = FormatPercent((wsArrD2 - wsArrC2) / (wsArrD2 + wsArrC2), 2)
 PercentVar2 = FormatPercent((wsArrD2 - wsArrC3) / (wsArrD2 + wsArrC3), 2)
 PercentVar3 = FormatPercent((wsArrC3 - wsArrC2) / (wsArrC3 + wsArrC2), 2)
```

> In this formula you don't need to multiply it by 100 because:
>   **FormatPercent Returns an expression formatted as a percentage (that is, multiplied by 100) with a trailing % character.**

[For more info please visit FormatPercent Function (Visual Basic) on msdm.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zh1kxd7(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, @Mertinc